# Is it possible to compute this using Euler? $\frac{(\cos 1 + \cos 89)(\cos 2+\cos 88)\cdots(\cos 44 + \cos 46)}{\cos 1\cos 2\cdots\cos 44}$

Tags: trigonometry, euler-mascheroni-constant

> Is it possible to compute this using Euler?
>
> $$\dfrac{(\cos(1) + \cos (89))(\cos(2)+\cos(88))...(\cos(44) + \cos(46))}{\cos(1)\cos(2)...\cos(44)}$$

I have easily computed this problem using trigonometric identities but I'm looking for a way where Euler is used. I used the fact that $\cos(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix} +e^{-ix}}{2}$. Surprisingly, there's no negative term.

Comment: Use $\cos (a+b) + \cos (a-b)$ to simplify it...

Comment: Are these numbers supposed to be be in degrees or radians?

Comment: In degree, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$\cos x+\cos(90-x)=2\cos45\cos(45-x)$ for $1\le x\le44$

Alternatively

$\cos x+\cos(90-x)=\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt2\cos(45-x)$

Comment: Isn't $2 \cos 45$ also $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, Where has it been refuted?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice `alternatively`